# Как вывести значение колонок двух таблиц с одинаковыми именами

Tags: php, yii

Как вывести значение id из двух таблиц б/д advert и category.
В даный момент выводит только значение $adver->id.

```
 public function actionIndex() {
                $advert = Advert::model()->findAllBySql('SELECT * FROM o_advert');                         
                $this->render('index', array('model' => $advert));

        $c = Advert::model()->findAllBySql('SELECT * FROM o_category');                         
                $this->render('index', array('model' => $c)); 
            }

        <?php foreach (array_reverse($model) as $adver) { ?> 
        <?php echo $adver->id; ?>
        <?php echo $adver->title; ?>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php foreach ($model as $c) { ?> 
        <?php echo $c->id; ?>
        <?php echo $c->description; ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том что во view вы переписывали $model. Нужно просто результат выборки в разные переменные поместить.

```
$this->render('index', array('a_model'=> $advert)); 
....
$this->render('index',array('c_model'=> $c)); 
...
<?php foreach (array_reverse($a_model) as $adver) { ?> 
<?php echo $adver->id; ?>
<?php echo $adver->title; ?>
<?php } ?>

<?php foreach ($c_model as $c) { ?> 
<?php echo $c->id; ?>
<?php echo $c->description; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Немного по-русски задачу опиши, реально я 3 раза прочитал и не понял.

> Как вывести значение колонок двух таблиц с одинаковыми именами

2 таблицы с одинаковыми именами, или в таблицах есть поля одинаковые

```
<?php foreach (array_reverse($model) as $adver) { ?> 
        <?php echo $adver->id; ?>
        <?php echo $adver->title; ?>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php foreach ($model as $c) { ?> 
        <?php echo $c->id; ?>
        <?php echo $c->description; ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

Это что код на php????

если уж пишешь такой "бред" так хоть в логику вникни.

public function actionIndex() {
                $advert = Advert::model()->findAllBySql('SELECT * FROM o_advert');                       
                $c = Advert::model()->findAllBySql('SELECT * FROM o_category');                       
                $this->render('index', array( 'm' => $advert, 'mo' => $c)); 
            }

```
<?php foreach (array_reverse($m) as $adver) {
echo $adver->id;
echo $adver->title;
}
foreach ($mo as $c) {
echo $c->id; 
echo $c->description;
} ?>
```

я все понимаю но синтаксис не просто хромает он еще даже не родился.